# Unable to import iPhoto 11 Library in OS X Lion

Tags: photos.app

I have an iPhoto 11 Library on an old Macbook Pro.

I just received a new Macbook Pro with a clean copy of iPhoto 11

I put my iPhoto Library into Dropbox and synced

When I try to import my iPhoto Library on my OS X Lion MacBook Pro I am unable to select the iPhoto Library because it is greyed out.

How can I import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't import it.

Never import one Library to another. Every version and thumbnail is imported like a distinct photo, you lose all your Albums, Keywords etc., the link between Original and Previews is destroyed, the non-destructive editing feature is ruined and so on. In summary: it's mess.

You want to migrate the Library - just drag it to where ever you want it and open it: Hold down the option (or alt) key key and launch iPhoto. From the resulting menu select 'Choose Library'

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl click the iPhoto lib and select Show Package contents, go to Originals and pull the photos out of the lib and import.

Comment: While this will get the original photos it will get nothing else - edits, edit history, books, slideshows, keywords, added metadata and so on.